# Web Service (UiPath Orchestrator) unavailable on public internet but on local machine

Tags: server, windows-server-2016, uipath

I installed UiPath Orchestrator and followed the installation step by step ([manual](https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/docs/the-windows-installer)). I have opened all ports mentioned in the guide.
[image: Added Firewalls]

As Inbound and Outbound rule just to be sure. Now the problem is, everything works fine on the local machine with the exception that the server is only available through it's computer name.

[image: Browser demo]

But even though I'm on the same machine, when I try to connect through my ip address and the port (443) then I get:

```html
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

I should mention that the ssl certificate is just a self-signed one and we do not have a domain, just the ip address since it's a cloud instance from ibm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So guys this was a really small but important fact. 
In the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager on the bindings, it's important to have a binding with no hostname otherwise it won't work.

[image: Bindings setup]

So with this configured the connection is available on the public internet without any issues.

Comment: you basically need your machine to answer to any request it receives. Otherwise it will only respond if the request match the hostname